# Rails 3 - Record.send not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a view that shows all of my customers.  I have a Customer model that is backing this view.  There is a method in the model that will change an attribute from "" to a persons initials, "jh".  Here is the method.

```
def print(item, attribute)
  value = item.send(attribute)
  if(value.blank?)
    item.send(attribute + '=', "jh")
  else
    item.send(attribute + '=', "")
  end
end
```

When I run this code from the console, it works perfectly.  When I try it in the app, nothing changes.  I am getting the proper 'value' that I expect, but it is never turned into an empty string.  I am sure I am missing something simple here, but please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this code, and I tried it on both a plain ruby object and on an ActiveRecord model and both worked as expected. So I suspect something funny is happening that is specific to your code.

I would suggest in any case that rather than construct a setter via string concatenation, you should use Ruby's native [`instance_variable_set`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set):

```
def print(item, attribute)
  value = item.send(attribute)
  if(value.blank?)
    item.instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", "jh")
  else
    item.instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", "")
  end
end
```

One caveat with this method is that it will create an instance variable if none previously existed.

Comment: Could you post your complete code where I can see it?  I am trying to recreate this in any project, so I can see where I am making my error.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I have to add item.save for it to commit to the database.  I did not have to do this in the erb.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't understand "in the erb". You mean in the view?

Comment: Of course you have to save the attribute if you want it to persist between requests... but that's beyond the question you asked. The code you had works as it should.

Comment: I didnt have to do that in the console.  Sorry for the ignorance, just learning.  Thanks for the help.